# Replace item in dictionary of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, replace

I have a dictionary like the following:

```
info = {
    # Many more entries similar to this one
    'library1' : {'files' : ['path1', 'path2', 'path3_replace', 'path4']}
}
```

My goal is to search for and replace `path3_replace` with a different path. Here is what I have tried:

```
new_path = "was_replaced"


for lib in info:
    m = info[lib]
    for path in m['files']:
        if "replace" in path:
            path = new_path
            print(path)


# Here I'm just trying to print all paths to show if it worked or not

for lib in info:
    m = info[lib]
    for path in m['files']:
        print(path)
```

The console output displayed is the following:

```
was_replaced
path1
path2
path3_replace
path4
```

Clearly, the string in the dictionary is not being replaced and is still `path3_replace`. The desired output is:

```
was_replaced
path1
path2
was_replaced
path4
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you for any help!

Edit: I purposefully left the code example very vague to isolate the problem

Comment: For those who downvoted, can I receive a comment or reason? I would like to help out however I can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string in the dict is not being replaced, because you never changed it.  You changed the loop index, not its data source.  To change the list element, you have to access the list.

```
for idx, path in enumerate(m['files']):
    if "replace" in path:
        m['files'][idx] = new_path
        print(m['files'][idx])
```

`path` is simply a local variable.

Comment: Awesome that worked! I'm newer to python and was unaware that `path` was just a local variable, I accepted your answer but am unable to upvote it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped.  Yes, it takes a few weeks to get used to how variables work.  `path` is a new scalar you made, that starts life as a copy of the value from your list.